# iOS Tab Bar Icon Clicked Event

Tags: ios, xcode, ios6, click, tabbar

I am trying to execute some code when a tab bar button/icon is pressed - even if that button/icon is currently active. 
How do I do that?
All I find is words like "`delegate`" which mean nothing to me as I come from php world. If anyone can point me to youtube video where this is done on a current Xcode (4.6.1) iOS version 6.1 as most answers I find are either on old Xcode that look nothing like the current one or too vague, that I cannot decipher.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the selected index of the tabbar with:

```
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex
```

Comment: am after an event, I want to execute code when user taps on the tabbar item

Comment: Tabbar is for navigate view

Comment: I am refering to this as "tab Bar" http://ios-blog.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/fourth-view.png